# Ask Ubuntu moderator?

Tags: support

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319792/ubuntu-does-not-recognize-existing-windows-partitions-in-a-gpt-disk) post where the OP @[Pops](https://askubuntu.com/users/174972/pops) is indicated to be a moderator. ..a little surprised! Are there more moderators than the community elected ones mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/election? If yes, is there a page that lists them all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides [**our site's elected moderators**](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators), Stack Exchange has [**community managers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/185080), who have moderator powers across the whole network. [Pops (a.k.a. Kevin Chang)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/community-management-by-popular-demand-kevin-chang-joins-the-team/) is [one such person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131713/pops).

Most of the duties of moderators on Ask Ubuntu are carried out by our elected moderators. Sometimes, the community managers step in. They are available to assist moderators, and also to help settle any disputes that may arise involving moderators.

And they do administrative work that is not localized to any particular site, moderating [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and helping set up new sites (including appointing [moderators who serve before a site's first moderator election](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)).

#### Work Cited (and further reading)

- [Who are the Community Team, and what do they do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do)